# setBroadcast method

Tags: java, networking

what is a `setBroadcast` method in java? I have tried searching,but cannot understand it's function.
Please explain clearly.

Comment: Related documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setBroadcast(boolean)

Comment: Have you tried reading the Javadoc? No need to 'search'.

Answer (score 4):

You're talking about DatagramSocket.setBroadcast(boolean), I assume.

To prevent accidental broadcasts, you have to set this flag to true before you can broadcast datagrams. This is actually a feature of IPv4, not something specific to Java networking. With IPv4 you have to set a socket's SO_BROADCAST flag before you can use it to broadcast. The Java method just allows you to set it from Java.

Comment: Is it just for a sending socket, for a receiving too (that wants to receive broadcast packets) or for both?